# Modi verbali in una frase con la struttura "sembra che più ..., più ..."

Tags: subjunctive-mood

Buongiorno,
è corretto scrivere "Sembra che, più io amo la musica, più lei mi respinga"? o è "più" corretto "sembra che, più io ami la musica, più lei mi respinga"?

Per la verità, ho anche il dubbio che si possa dire "Sembra che, più amo la musica, più lei mi respinge".

C'è una regola ben precisa che renda univoco l'uso dei modi verbali in una frase con questa struttura? Potreste aiutarmi, per favore?

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: La mia impressione è che l'uso del congiuntivo in questa frase non abbia a che vedere con la struttura correlativa "più ... più", ma con la presenza del "sembra che": senza il "sembra che" si userebbe l'indicativo: "più io amo la musica, più lei mi respinge". Con il "sembra che" direi che di regola si debba usare il congiuntivo perché i due verbi "amare" e "respingere" dipendono dal "sembra che".

Comment: Sì e no, @Charo, perché effettivamente non è ovvio se entrambe le subordinate richiedano il congiuntivo. Personalmente riformulerei un po' la frase come “Sembra che la musica mi respinga tanto più quanto più io la amo”, ma preferirei in realtà semplificarla: “A quel che sembra, più amo la musica, più lei mi respinge”.

Comment: Mmm... Hai ragione, @DaG: si tratta di qualcosa di simile a una doppia subordinata, quindi non è per niente ovvio.

Comment: Io ho l'impressione che la virgola dopo il *che* separi il "più io amo la musica" dal resto, per cui preferisco lì l'indicativo. Anche tutte le frasi espresse con l'indicativo comunque non è (ultimamente) considerato sbagliato.

Comment: @DaG:  So che non vuol dire nulla, ma su [questo libro](https://books.google.es/books?id=14qMBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT26&dq=%22sembra+che+pi%C3%B9%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwizlJCimPDqAhVc8uAKHbqeAjU4MhDoATABegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=%22sembra%20che%20pi%C3%B9%22&f=false) se ne trova un esempio con tutti i verbi al congiuntivo: "sembra che più nevrotici siano i personaggi, più il pubblico li ami e li identifichi".